# Why file_get_contents doen't work with https when I use graph-api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

```
file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE');
```

When I open this link in browser with my access token It gives a list of all of my Facebook pages and when I try to echo it with `file_get_contents`, it gives the following error:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied
>   in /home/www/***********************.php on line 4

Also `file_get_contents` works fine with any other website.

Comment: Can you `file_get_contents` on a different https url?

Comment: A _permission denied_ error on a HTTPS request? That’s strange, permission errors usually occur in the local file system, but not when using HTTP(S). I’d rather expect an HTTP error code.

Comment: Eldar
I checked it.. I can't get file_get_contents on any other URL too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` before every line containing `curl_exec` in base_facebook.php if you are using php sdk. 
If it works then you can at lease know where the issue is.